# How to show marker clusters based on region?

Tags: r, leaflet, react-leaflet

Based on this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817268/shiny-leaflet-display-labels-based-on-zoom-level), I want the markers clusters on my map to be displayed such that they are based on their specific regions. But I can't get it to work. As of now the marker clusters are displayed based on areas on the map where most markers are located. But I want them to be displayed such that it can be seen that the regions like North, Central, North-East, West and East can be seen on the map.

Here's a snapshot of the leaflet map
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CsmZ.jpg)

Here's my code

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Transactions for Resale Flats"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("year","Year", choices = c("",headlinedata$year))),
        mainPanel(leafletOutput("mymap", width = 1500 ,height = 1000)))


)


server <- function(input,output, session){

    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addCircleMarkers(data = headlinedata , 
                                                               lng = ~lon , 
                                                               lat = ~lat , radius = 10 , 
                                                               clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
    })

    observeEvent(
        eventExpr = input$map_zoom,{
            print(input$map_zoom)
            leafletProxy(mapId = 'mymap',
                         session=session
                         )%>%
                          clearMarkers()%>%
                          addMarkers(
                              data=headlinedata,
                              lng=~lon,
                              lat=~lat,
                              label=if(input$map_zoom<6)~region
                          )
        }
    )

}
```

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Here's an example of my data

```
town <-c('Ang Mo Kio','Sembawang','Clementi','Pasir Ris','Yishun')
region <-c('North_East','North','West','East','North')                  
flat_type <-c('3 ROOM','3 ROOM','4 ROOM','5 ROOM','4 ROOM')
lat <-c(1.377804,1.450675,1.312938,1.377781,1.422404)
lon <-c(103.8381    ,103.8189,103.7716, 103.9405,103.8465)

qns <-data.frame(town,region,flat_type,lat,lon)
```